# how to access collection member labels in collection extension

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have extended the `collection` form field type with `CollectionTableExtension`.  I am trying to set a variable, `FormView::$vars['headers']` so that  `collection` can be output with default headers when `is_table` is `true` and no user-defined headers are available. The default headers should be the same as the labels which would normally be applied to collection members.

e.g.

if `FooType` has 3 fields, `foo`, `bar` and `fibble`, its labels will be Foo, Bar and Fibble (after humanizing with Twig template) or the values stored in the `label` attribute of each property.

So if my `DoofusType` has a collection of `FooType`s,

```
$builder->add('foos', 'collection', array('type'=>'acc_foo', 'is_table'=>true));
```

should result in a view where headings for the collection will be Foo, Bar and Fibble or the values of the label attributes of the `FooType` if they are set.

Here is my `collection` extension:

```
<?php
namespace ACC\MainBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class CollectionTableExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setOptional(array('is_table'));
        $resolver->setOptional(array('headers'));
        $resolver->setOptional(array('caption'));
    }

    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return 'collection';
    }


    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if (array_key_exists('is_table', $options)) {
            $view->vars['is_table'] = $options['is_table'];

            if (array_key_exists('caption', $options))  $view->vars['caption'] = $options['caption'];   

            if (array_key_exists('headers', $options)) {
                $view->vars['headers'] = $options['headers'];
            }else{
                //harvest labels from  collection members, but HOW?
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The issue is that I don't know how to access the properties of the collection element type from inside the collection extension. I could access the first element in the collection like this:

```
if($form->has('0')) {
    foreach($form->get('0')->all() as $item)
        $view->vars['headers'][] = $item->getName();
}
```

but that doesn't help if the collection is empty. And it doesn't help if the collection element type has defined labels.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After much slogging through Symfony source code, I've found a way to do it.  Essentially, in `::buildView` a dummy collection element of the correct type must be instantiated so that its labels or properties can be extracted.  Here's what I did:

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if (array_key_exists('is_table', $options)) {
        $view->vars['is_table'] = $options['is_table'];

        if (array_key_exists('caption', $options))  $view->vars['caption'] = $options['caption'];   

        if (array_key_exists('headers', $options)) {
            if($options['headers']===false){ //no headers
                unset($view->vars['headers']);
            }else if (is_array($options['headers'])){ //headers passed in
                $view->vars['headers'] = $options['headers'];
            }
        }else { //harvest labels from  collection elements
            $elementtype = $form->getConfig()->getOption('type');

            //should be a guard clause here so types that won't supply good headers (e.g. a collection of text fields) will skip the rest

            $element = $form->getConfig()->getFormFactory()->create($elementtype); //get dummy instance of collection element
            $fields = $element->all(); 
            $headers = array();
            foreach($fields as $field){
                $label= $field->getConfig()->getOption('label');
                $headers[] = empty($label) ? $field->getName() : $label;
            }
            $view->vars['headers'] = $headers;

        }
    }
}
```

If anyone has a cleaner method, I'm all ears.